# How to edit 1000 records at time using entity framework in less time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
public ActionResult EditRow()
{
        using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
        {
            var v = db.Students.ToList();
            return View(v);
        }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditRow(List<Student> student)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
            {
                foreach (var i in student)
                {
                    var c = db.Students.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(i.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        c.LastName = i.LastName;
                        c.FirstMidName = i.FirstMidName;
                        c.EnrollmentDate = i.EnrollmentDate;
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Successfully updated";
            return View(student);

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "failed";
            return View(student);
}
```

Right now I have implemented this code,but server takes more time to edit records. Is there any way to edit records quickly?
How can I minimise Execution time? 
and how to check time complexity in Visual studio?

Comment: Instead of loading each Student separately, can you make a list of IDs and then load all Students with an ID in that list? Then loop over that in-memory list to update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very useful Entity Framework Extension available at 
https://entityframework-extensions.net/

It is also available as a nuget package.  This extension gives you bulk updates and inserts and works very well.

The nuget package can be installed with this command from the package manager window `Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Extensions`

The above packages appears to be a commercial package now but I know there are some similar extension libraries out there that do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would remark this question as already answered. There are a lot of stated answers how-to-do, if you searching for keywords like "ef bulk updates".

This is a known issue when using e.g. entity-framework-6. As above @John S has already mentioned you can use extension libraries for bulk updates. I am not sure what you mean with "time complexity" in that context. If you use an OR mapper, you should profile your SQL statements anyway, [e.g. SQL Profiler](https://royaljay.com/development/debugging-entity-framework-sql-server-profiler/).